# Display nested loops object in html list ul li

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, html-lists, nested-loops

Hi I have this object

```
{
 levela: {
  levelb: {
    levelc: [],
    leveld: []
  }
 }, 
 level1: {
   level2: {
     level3: {
       level4:[]
     }
   }
 }
}
```

I want convert this in ul li items like this, I just want to stop if I object[key] is an array

```
<ul>
 <li>levela
  <ul>
   <li>levelb
      <ul>
         <li>levelc</li>
      </ul>
   </li>

  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>level1</li>
  ....
</ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Time to use [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)!

Hope you don't render that component often...

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect
} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    levela: {
      levelb: {
        levelc: [],
        leveld: []
      }
    },
    level1: {
      level2: {
        level3: {
          level4: []
        }
      }
    }
  })

  const renderData = (data) => {
    let id = 1;
    
    function* renderRecurse(data) {
      if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        for (let item of data) {
          yield (<li key={id++}>{item}</li>)
        }
        return;
      }

      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        yield (<ul key={id++}><li key={id++}>{key}</li>{[...renderRecurse(value)]}</ul>)
      }
    }
    
    return [...renderRecurse(data)]
  }

  return <div>{renderData(data)}</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.10.1/polyfill.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```